# Is it possible to divide a button into clickable parts?

Tags: xcode5

Say I have an image of a wheel thats is divided into equal parts and each part has a different color. I wonder if it's possible to divide it as a button into measured regions so that each region can be clickable and has a different function.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to get the coordinates of the click event, and figure out what part of the circle it is on.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I'll try to do that.